# Liquibase-Snowflake extension (API) unable to connect to liquibase versions 3.7.0+, hence unable to use env var in changeset

Tags: environment-variables, liquibase, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently using, liquibase maven version: 3.5.3 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core) which is the only version that works with snowflake using liquibase.
Normal schema related changes are all working fine and great with upper named schema's. But issue here is, when using environment variables in actual sql or changesets. (Liquibase is unable to integrate this prior to sending changeset to snowflake for execution).

Liquibase updated this: [CORE-3205] - Change Log Parameters from Environment Variable, on 20 Aug 2019. But https://github.com/CDKGlobal/liquibase-snowflake hasn't been updated for more than 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

The liquibase-snowflake extension is back under active development and is currently using liquibase-core 3.10.0, https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-snowflake/blob/main/pom.xml#L45.